# Is there any way to use latest nodejs version (18) with expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo, npx

I'm encountering an issue while trying to create a React Native Expo project. When running the command npx create-expo-app my-app, I receive warnings that include the following message: WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the versioned Expo CLI (npx expo).

The problem arises because I have NodeJS 18 installed on my system, and I prefer not to downgrade to NodeJS 16, which is suggested as a solution in various sources. I believe using NodeJS 18 should be compatible with creating the Expo project. Is there a way to resolve this issue without downgrading NodeJS?

I have also attached an image for reference:

[image]

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `expo-cli` has support for node version higher than node 16. As you mentioned you don't want to downgrade your node version, any specific reason for that?
Moreover, you can use `nvm` to have multiple node versions installed on your system and you can specify the version of node you want to use for a project.

## Installing NVM and using it:

1. You can get the latest nvm depending on your system from [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases).

2. Once you have successfully installed NVM, install the node version you want: `nvm install vX.Y.Z` -> Specify the version you want to install in place of X.Y.Z
3. Now, to use the installed version use- `nvm use vA.B.C`.

Comment: I wanna use latest nodejs with expo....how can I do that?

Comment: That's what I said in my answer, Expo doesn't support node higher than 16 as of now.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to use the global expo-cli package at all anymore, it is deprecated. use `npx expo` within the project to invoke the cli from the local `expo` package within the project. eg: `npx expo start`. not all commands live on this new local cli package, for example you can use `npx expo-doctor` to use the npm package `expo-doctor` instead of `expo doctor`. see this blog post for more information: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421

Comment: I'm using `npx` when creating a project, but still it warns me about nodejs version

Comment: in your screenshot you are running `expo doctor`. run `npx expo-doctor` for the equivalent that does not use the deprecated "global" expo-cli package

Comment: now after using `npx expo-doctor` it tells me that `'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` am using terminal for executing commands on windows